# Multiple columns from a single column of data file

Tags: list-manipulation, import

Suppose I have a data file containing one column of 1000 rows having x, y, z and ϕ values. I need to separate them into four distinct columns by selecting every alternative value.

For example, if I have a column such as {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}, then I need to select {a,c,e,g,i} for one column and {b,d,f,h,j} for another column.

```
z = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: If `crange = CharacterRange["a", "z"]` then consider: `(t0 = Partition[crange, 4]) // Column` or `t1 = Transpose@Partition[crange, 4]`. I am not sure which one you want. Do you want to rewrite this file back as a four column file? If so, can you include a smaller sample file with perhaps 100 entries.

Comment: Yes, actually, the data file contains a single column having x,y,z, and phi values. I need to separate them into four distinct columns

Comment: @user84456 From your last description, then would a simple `Partition[z, 4]` work?

Comment: If `Partition` produces a 'ragged' array, perhaps you require `Flatten[Partition[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k},UpTo[2]],{{2}}]` (which in this case gives  **{{a, c, e, g, i, k}, {b, d, f, h, j}}**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you seek, then with `z = Range[32]` for clarity, maybe:

```
First@ Multicolumn[z, {4, Automatic}]

(* Out: 
{{1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29},
 {2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30}, 
 {3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31}, 
 {4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32}}
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

First save a list of random numbers to a file to create a mock experiment:

```
alist = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]
Export["C:/alist.txt", alist, "List"]
```

Then read it back like so:

```
t1=ReadList["C:/alist.txt", {Number, Number, Number, Number}]
```

Export it back like this:

```
Export["C:/alist2.txt", t1, "Table"]
```

Try `Table` and `List` as formats to see the difference.